# Mobile Safari - tap and hold -webkit-tap-highlight-color + event delegation issue

Tags: javascript, css, ios, mobile, webkit

Can anyone explain why tapping and holding anywhere inside this default [modal](http://www.richardscarrott.co.uk/assets/javascript/jquery/modal/demo/) other than an anchor on an iPad (maybe iPhone too) causes the entire element to highlight as if it's clickable and prevents you from copying and pasting...

I've found this seems to happen on a number of elements which shouldn't be considered 'clickable'.

**EDIT**
So I've just noticed that stackoverflow itself suffers from this issue if you try to select the text (tap and hold) in this question.

The code that is causing it on the modal script isn't anything out of the ordinary:

```
// JS
$('.modal').delegate('.modal-close', 'click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // close modal
});

// HTML
<div class="modal"> <span class="modal-close">Close X</span> </div>
```

Comment: Thinking about it it's probably because I'm delegating the close link event from the .modal element however that shouldn't prevent default if it's not the close element surely...

Comment: Based on that thought I've come across this: http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/10/01/quick-tip-customizing-the-mobile-safari-tap-highlight-color/ However the crap thing about this is -webkit-tap-highlight-color is an inherited property so all child elements have the highlight removed too. On top of this copy and paste still appears to be prevented. Is this a massive oversight that'll result in event delegation not being used on mobile safari devices (where it probably has the most benefit)!?

Comment: Can you provide the selector and html you're using.